# how to add more text to a string before a special char

Tags: javascript

I would like to modify a string using jQuery as following:

Existing value: `myimage_one.png`
New value: `myimage_one_notold.png`

How can I do it? Maybe with the `concat()` function?

Comment: var newVar = existingVar.replace(".", "notold.");

Comment: '.' (dot) is special character only, I see underscore as well. Is your string a kind of file name with ext always ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` function on your string. In this case you could replace the `.png` with `_notold.png`:

```js
var foo = 'myimage_one.png';
var bar = foo.replace('.png', '_notold.png');
console.log(bar);
```

Alternatively, you can use this regular expression if you want to only remove the last instance of the `.`, in cases where the filename contains more than one:

```js
var foo = 'myimage_one.png';
var bar = foo.replace(/\.([^\.]*)$/,'_notold.$1');
console.log(bar);
```

Also note that both of the above use native JS methods and havenothing to do with jQuery

Comment: It might be noteworthy that this will fail if the filename has several occurrences of `.png` as `replace()` only replaces the first occurrance found.

Comment: @connexo very true. I've updated the answer with a simple regex which will only replace the last instance of the found character.

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceString(org_str,replace_with)
{   
var found_str = org_str.substring(org_str.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); 
return org_str.replace(found_str, replace_with);    
}
```

Comment: this is more beautiful than my solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you always want to append the string before the last `.` you can use split:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var strArr = existingVar.split('.');
var newString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    if (i+1 < strArr.length) {
    newString += strArr[i];
    } else {
        newString += "_notOld"+ strArr[i+1];     
    }
}
alert(newString);
```

this should do the job in every case, with each filetype and name (for example: `my.new.file.is.cool.jpg` should work as well as `myFile.png` or `myImage.yeah.gif`)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have any series of letters, numbers, underscore or dash after the last dot in the file name, then:

`filename = filename.replace(/(\.[\w\d_-]+)$/i, '_notold$1');`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the changes using the following method,

```
var existingVal = "myimage_one.png";
var modifiedVal = exisitingVal.replace(".","_notold.");
```